# Model in header doesn't appear in views that use the header

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Model defined in the header of my pages appears on page load and refresh on the main page, but when I navigate to another view the model doesn't appear there. The rest of the header is there, just the dynamic data that isn't.

Where am I going wrong? New to both Python and Django, so if anyone can help, please don't be afraid to patronize and Eli5 :)

Model defined in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Propaganda(models.Model):
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slogan
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Christopher's weblog</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Blog site.">

        <!-- Let's get the static files where we use them, but this could be before the html tag -->
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/bulma.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/cupar.css' %}" type="text/css" /> -->
    </head>    
    <body>

        <section class="hero is-success is-bold">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container">
                    {% block slogan %}
                        {% for propaganda in propagandas %}
                            <h6>{{ propaganda.slogan }} it's</h6>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endblock %}
                    <h1 class="title" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                            </span>
                        <a href="{% url 'post_list' %}">The Guide</a>
                    </h1>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">                            
                            <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="button is-warning is-pulled-right">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>New post</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                </div><!-- @container -->
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- content under header in here-> -->
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Post, Propaganda
from .forms import PostForm
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    propagandas = Propaganda.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'propagandas': propagandas})
```

post_detail.html (where the model does not appear):

```
{% extends 'blog/header.html' %}

{% block content  %}
some html / form that has nothing to do with the header.
{% endblock %}
```

post_list.html (the 'index' page where the model works fine)

```
{% extends "blog/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for post in posts %}
        <section class="section">
        more html 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: are you sure you are passing the models to the other view function render shortcuts being returned for detail?

Comment: So where is the view that renders post_detail? Is it passing the data for the header?

Comment: @SciGuyMcQ Ah, that was the fix, yes. I added "propagandas = Propaganda.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]" to the post_detail in views.py and also repeated the 'propagandas': propagandas. I have a lot to learn about django. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  @ Daniel  - yes, I omitted that not thinking it was important, but it was important!

Comment: Note, the usual way of dealing with items that need to be shown on every page is to write a custom template tag.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Why are you not showing the view of post_detail. Isn't that the one that does not work?

**Second:** Even though you are extending a base template you still have to pass the appropriate context in order to generate the desired dynamic data.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! It does help thank you! What was obvious to everyone else was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

need to pass the data from each view function that is required in the header you are extending (re-using) in each template.

```
def post_detil(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    propagandas = Propaganda.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]

    # ... add in other stuff relevant to post details ...
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'posts': posts, 'propagandas': propagandas, 'post': post})
```

Stick with it @Rin and Len, you'll get there :)